# Given $3\cos x - 4 \sin x = 2$, find $3 \sin x + 4 \cos x$ without first solving for $x$

Tags: trigonometry

If $$3\cos{x}-4\sin{x}=2$$
find $$3\sin{x} +4\cos{x} $$

I have solved the equation for $x$, then calculated the required value, but I think there is a direct solution without solving the equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$3\sin x+4\cos x=A$$
$$3\cos x-4\sin x=2$$
$$9\sin^2x+24\sin x\cos x+16\cos^2x=A^2$$
$$9\cos^2x-24\sin x\cos x+16\sin^2x=4$$
add both equations
$$9+16=A^2+4$$
$$A^2=21$$
$$A=\pm \sqrt{21}$$

Comment: this is a $2$ not a $4$.

Comment: $A^2=9$ has *two* solutions.

Comment: sorry. now i'll change solution

Comment: You squared equations and lost equivalence in the way, so which one of $+\sqrt{21}$ and $-\sqrt{21}$ is legit ? If both, why ?

Comment: both of them are legit: negative value $-\sqrt{21}$ was when $cosx<0$ and $sinx<0$ positive value: was  when $cosx>0$ and $sinx>0$. Equation $3cosx−4sinx=2$ has two solutions on the circle.

Comment: yep, you can as well say that if $x$ gives $A$ then $x+\pi$ gives $-A$.

Comment: @zwim you are right

Answer (score 3):

Think of it as a rotation equation. This is equivalent to the matrix formulation $$\begin{bmatrix} \cos x & -\sin x \\ \sin x & \cos x\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ y \end{bmatrix}$$ where y is the unknown. Since the magnitude of a vector is preserved in rotation, $2^2 + y^2 = 3^2 + 4^2$ So, $y = \pm \sqrt {21}$.

Comment: It needs to be $y=\pm\sqrt{21}$. Both values are possible.

Comment: @user236182 You're right, it's corrected.

Answer (score 1):

$$a \cos(x) - b \sin(x) = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \cos(x+y)$$ where $\cos(y) = a/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\sin(y) = b/\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.  Then $$a \sin(x) + b \cos(x) = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \sin(x+y)$$
In your case, with $a=3$ and $b=4$, $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=5$, $\cos(x+y) = 2/5$ so $\sin(x+y) = \pm \sqrt{1-(2/5)^2} = \pm  \sqrt{21}/5$, so the answer is $\pm \sqrt{21}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is really the same as aid78's method.

$$(3+4i)e^{ix}=(3\cos x-4\sin x)+i(3\sin x+4\cos x)
=2+iA$$
for $A=3\sin x+4\cos x$. As $|(3+4i)e^{ix}|^2=3^2+4^2=25$
then $25=4+A^2$, so $A=\pm\sqrt{21}$ (both are possible).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Using [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_Identity),
$$(a\cos x-b\sin x)^2+(a\sin x+b\cos x)^2=(a^2+b^2)(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)=?$$